# RethinkDB-DB not found

Tags: python, rethinkdb

I have installed rethinkdb on my local machine and the Python driver.However Im unable to access a database I want..The name of the database is "authors" and the table is "books".

I initially open the connection:

```
 r.connect(host = 'localhost',port = 28015).repl()
```

The connection is successful

Then  I run the following command:

```
 r.db('authors).table('books').count()
```

I get the error "db authors doesnt exist"...I have tried a few different queries but get the same error
(However if I want to create a new database I am able to do so-Im only unable to access already existing databases).

Comment: Does running `r.db_list()` return a list that contains 'authors'?

Comment: @AtnNn ....on running the list command i see that only the 'test' database is listed...where am I going wrong?

Comment: Make sure running `r.db_create('authors')` returns `{"created": 1}`

Comment: @AtnNn..that cleared it--Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your database and your table. RethinkDB doesn't automatically create them for you.

```
r.db_create("authors").run()
r.db("authors").table_create("books").run()
r.db("authors").table("books").count()
```

Comment: @neumino...Thanks!-Dint realize I had to create it